# How to store form data in a swift app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I'm working on my first app and I need some help understanding what kind of data storage I need. I'm familiar with PHP, SQL, and databases but I don't know where to start with this project.

The app is pretty much a basic form with text fields, pickers, and uploaded images. At the end, the user will press submit and all of their data will be sent in an email.

What is the best way to store their data, so the user can go to previous screens and have their previously entered info still there. And then what is the best way to store the data after they press submit to send it in an email?,

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing data in Swift iOS app for later use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307648/storing-data-in-swift-ios-app-for-later-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class called `NSUserDefaults`

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() //make an instance
defaults.setObject("Bob", forKey: "myName") //storing a value 
defaults.synchronize() //synchronize data 
println(defaults.objectForKey("myName")!) //retrieve the data
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think I'm going to use this and use MFMailComposeViewController to send everything in an email

Comment: I believe ````MFMailComposeViewController```` will require the user to confirm and click a send button showing a preview of the email before it is sent. If you want to skip all of that and do everything automatically after the user clicks submit, and have the data send over an http request to the php server, to a small php scipt that uses the ````mail()```` function.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just form data that you're storing once for submission, for simplicity sake, I recommend just stuffing it in a global dictionary that you can access from different views. Swift makes this easy by just adding an empty swift file and defining your dictionary at the top:

```
var myFormData: [String: AnyObject]()
```

You can now access "myFormData" form anywhere in your app, add and remove stuff from it.

You shouldn't technically need to "reload previous views" because of the way the navigation stack works. Anything you go back to should hold it's info.

If you really need to save the data to allow the user to close the app and then pick up where they left off much later, then I recommend simply kicking your dictionary to NSUserDefaults. It doesn't sound like something that needs to involve a database.

Comment: I'm using segues between view controllers and they're 'present modally' I'm not sure if this is an issue but my data is deleting when going between view controllers. If i put a text field on one and go to the next view and then go back the data is gone. Is there a special segue I should be using?

Comment: Are you clearing it on "viewDidAppear" or something because even with a modal you should be able to display it and dismiss it and still hold the data on the original view. If all else fails, I suppose just re-loading the data manually (aka, setting the UI element values with your saved data on viewDidAppear) will work.